# How to instantiate class from static method of abstract class

Tags: typescript

I would like to know how to instantiate class from static method of abstract class. Something like:

```
abstract class F {
  static connect() {
    console.log("constructor => ", this.constructor);
    this.constructor();
  }

  constructor() {
    console.log("Hey!");
  }
}

class A extends F {
  constructor() {
    super();
    console.log("hey");
  }
}
```

Comment: You can not initialize the abstract class. You can only extend from an abstract class and initialize the child class. Or you can just make the `F` class not abstract and just return 
`new F()` from `connect()` method

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When I did something similar, using `new this()` did not work for me, I resorted to using reflection to create the instance.

> The static Reflect.construct() method acts like the new operator, but as a function. It is equivalent to calling new target(...args). It gives also the added option to specify a different prototype.

[Source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Reflect/construct)

```
abstract class F {
  static connect<T extends F>(): T {
    console.log("constructor => ", this.constructor);
    return Reflect.construct(this, []) as T;
  }

  constructor() {
    console.log("Hey!");
  }
}
```

Next we create an instance of A:

```
const instanceOfA = A.connect();
```

Answer (score -1):

You *could* do it, but you probably shouldn't.

This idea seems like a big code smell to me.

What are you trying to achieve by it? In the best case scenario you're replacing `new A()` with `A.connect()`.
This just obfuscates what is happening and doesn't actually add anything.

I sadly can't tell you what the better approach would be without knowing more context, but I'd recommend re-thinking your design choices that led to this.

(And I do mean no offence by this. I've myself done pretty hacky bad code and JS and to a lesser degree TS allow for this. This was just meant as a friendly recommendation)

### How you could do it (for science)

```
class F {
  static connect() {
    return new this()
  }
}
```

If F is abstract, you could still do it using `return new (this as any)()` since javascript actually doesn't have abstract classes built-in.

Derived classes of `F` e.g. `A.connect()` will then create instances of `A`.

**However, this basically goes against both how static methods and Typescript are meant to be used**